# Нелинейный классификатор

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, классификация

Какие существуют алгоритмы классификации для линейно неразделимых данных, помимо многослойного перцептрона и ядерного SVM?

Ну или что бы все алгоритмы не перечислять(вдруг их много?), подскажите, какие способы существуют для работы с линейно неразделимыми данными? 
Например:

- Увеличение размерности пространства в методе опорных векторов
- Увеличение слоёв в искусственных нейронных сетях

Comment: Ни одного слова не понял, но погуглил и нашёл вот это: https://habrahabr.ru/post/312600/ :D

Comment: Привет. Могли бы Вы описать свою задачу. На абстрактный вопрос можно только абстрактно ответить.

Answer (score 0):

Как правило, все алгоритмы испльзуют ядра. Даже нейронные сети в скрытом виде их используют:

- ядерная логистическая регрессия;
- полиномиальная регрессия;
- разные виды препроцессинга и manifold learning (t-SNE, PCA (нелинейный));
- сети радиально базисных функций;
- все виды глубокого обучения.